# Unity Panel, Fcitx English icon issue. Can I fix icon width?

Tags: unity, indicator, input-method, notification-area, fcitx

iBus seems to be the default input method system for Ubuntu. But I have some problems with Mozc (Japanese input method) with iBus, so I chose to install Fcitx instead. The input methods are working fine, but I have a problem with the icon on the Unity's top bar.

In English mode, the icon is like this:
[image]
This is very wide. It contains a wide keyboard icon plus the "US" characters. It is almost twice as wide as the Mozc icon. This is problematic, because when I change the input mode, the icon width changes and all the icons on the left side of Fcitx moves. Not only is it visually annoying, when I try to right-click an application icon on the left side of Fcitx, the mode changes from keyboard icon alone to keyboard icon with "us", and the application icon's position changes, so the pop-up menu disappears.

At first I thought this keyboard icon with "us" is from Fcitx itself. Then I installed other desktop managers (Cinnamon and Mate) on the same system. On Cinnamon, Fcitx's English mode icon is like this: [image] This is the same width as Mozc. When I looked at `/usr/share/fcitx`, I cound only find that icon there.

So, I suspect this wide keyboard icon and "us" comes from Unity. As a matter of fact, the English mode is not an input method module of Fcitx, but rather an "off state", so this icon could be provided by Unity. Can I change this English mode icon to something else? Something squre and not with "us".

If that is not coming  from Unity, is there any way to fix this icon width forcibly, so that it would not change when I switch input methods?

Comment: I think the icons are stored as png files in /usr/share/fcitx I would imagine that you could resize it to meet your requirements with gimp.

Comment: No, I do not think the icon for the English mode is there.

Comment: Have you considered using `find` as in `find / -name *.png | grep "share/icons"`to locate the icon in question? (it's likely a .png file of small size

Comment: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps